Count all dates from daterange for every user
I have a table named holidays. They can send a request to an admin to make a holiday and the admin have to accept it. Now if the admin goes to the dashboard they see holidays request. I want to display how many holidays he had always in this year. How I do it?
SELECT

u.firstname,
u.lastname,

h.id,
h.user_id,
h.accepted_by,
h.accepted_by_admin,
h.admin_info,
h.user_info,
h.time_range,
h.created_at

FROM holidays h

INNER JOIN users u
ON h.user_id = u.id

WHERE h.tenant_id = $1 AND h.accepted_by_admin IS TRUE ORDER BY h.user_id, h.created_at LIMIT 50;

I have a column named time_range. This is a daterange data type like this:
[2024-10-13,2024-10-20)


Please review [mre]. Update the post with table DDL, sample data (preferably as excutable SQL), and expected output. One reason for requesting sample data and expected output is to help remove ambiguity; e.g., is the range [2024-10-13,2024-10-20) to be counted as one holiday or as seven days of holiday?

Do you want to count working days only? How about weekends, national holidays etc.?
